# While loop doesn't wait before displaying

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

In this code section, the query gets all the teachers and appends their assigned classes within the object

The weird thing is it works perfectly on local but not online, it is almost it doesn't wait for the while loop

```
<?php
$SID = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, htmlspecialchars($_POST["SID"], ENT_QUOTES));

$allTeachersArr = [];
$test = [];
$q = "SELECT onderwysers.*,klasse.Klas,klasse.Datum,klasse.Vak FROM `onderwysers` LEFT JOIN klasse ON onderwysers.ID = klasse.Teacher WHERE `SID` = '$SID'";
// echo $q;
$result = $con->query($q);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $subjectItem = new stdClass();

        $filtered_array = [];
        $isIn = false;
        $var1 = $row['ID'];
        $var2 = $row['Teacher'];
        if (count($allTeachersArr) > 0)
            foreach ($allTeachersArr as $item) {
                if ($item->ID == $var1 && $item->Teacher == $var2) {
                    // do something
                    $filtered_array = $item;
                    $isIn = true;
                }
            }
        if ($isIn == true) {
            $notAdd = false;
            // echo "updates";
            $subjectItem->Klas = $row["Klas"];
            $subjectItem->Datum = $row["Datum"];
            $subjectItem->Vak = $row["Vak"];
            foreach ($filtered_array->displaySubjects as $item) {
                if ($item->Klas == $row["Klas"] && $item->Vak == $row["Vak"] && $item->Datum == $row["Datum"]) {
                    // do something
                    $filtered_array = $item;
                    $notAdd = true;
                }
            }
            if ($notAdd == false) {
                $temp = $filtered_array->displaySubjects;
                array_push($temp, $subjectItem);
                $filtered_array->displaySubjects = $temp;
            }
        } else {
            //add new entry
            $subjectItem->ID = $row["ID"];
            $subjectItem->Title = $row["Title"];
            $subjectItem->Name = $row["Name"];
            $subjectItem->Surname = $row["Surname"];
            $subjectItem->Afkorting = $row["Afkorting"];
            $subjectItem->IdentityNumber = $row["IdentityNumber"];
            $subjectItem->Geslag = $row["Geslag"];
            $subjectItem->ContactDetails = $row["ContactDetails"];
            $subjectItem->Email = $row["Email"];
            $subjectItem->RegKlas = $row["RegKlas"];
            $subjectItem->Status = $row["Status"];
            $subjectItem->UID = $row["UID"];
            $subjectItem->displaySubjects = [];
            array_push($allTeachersArr, $subjectItem);
        }
    }
}

echo json_encode($allTeachersArr);
$con->close();
```

THE EXPECTED RETURNED DATA(This is local, online returns nothing)

[image]

Comment: Do you have data on the live DB? Did you check this?

Comment: Is the query failing on the live server?  How have you verified that it isn't?

Comment: Don't mix these two functions together `mysqli_real_escape_string($con, htmlspecialchars($_POST["SID"], ENT_QUOTES))`. They are used for completely different things. Please learn how to use prepared statements and stop escaping data in SQL

Comment: I made a dump from online and imported it locally so the data is the same.

Comment: Die query is working online... If we echo the data in the while loop we receive data back

Comment: Dharman, we used that to prevent SQL injection. What do you recommend we do there? Thank you